# Only show checked categories of Custom Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to display the names categories of a custom taxonomy called standard_engine_specification on a template page. This is what I have so far - it is showing all the categories of the taxonomy instead of just showing the ones checked in the admin panel.

```html
<?php
/*variable to retrieve checked term*/

 $ses_terms = get_the_terms( $id, 'standard_engine_specification' );
  if( $ses_terms && !is_wp_error( $ses_terms ) ) {
  foreach( $ses_terms as $term ) {

   }
  }
  /*variable used to filter results*/
  $ses_args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'standard_engine_specification',
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'tax_query' => array(array(
   'taxonomy' => 'standard_engine_specification',
   'field' => 'slug',
   'terms' => array($term->slug),
   'operator' => 'IN'
  ))
 );
    
?>
<ul>
<?php
/*output checked categories based on filter*/
foreach (get_categories($ses_args) as $category)
 {
  echo "<li>";
  echo $category->name;
  
  echo "</li>";
  
 }
?>
</ul>
```

I've pretty much Frankensteined this from some other scripts I have been using for filtering post types, maybe someone who knows what they are doing can tell me where and why I am missing this - I have put in some comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorted it. I did not need to use a tax_query, I tried to do the same thing I had done calling WooCommerce onto a template page but it was overkill, so we learn :)

```html
<?php

$ses_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'standard_engine_specification' );
if( $ses_terms && !is_wp_error( $ses_terms ) ) {
 foreach( $ses_terms as $term ) {
  echo "<li>";
  echo $term->name;
  echo "</li>";
 }
}
?>
```